# Getting an app-crashing Mongo error after the query succeeds

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

The `insert` succeeds and after the app crashes, it's all perfectly in the DB.

Schema:

```
/**
 * Section Schema
 */
var SectionSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
     required: true
  }
});

/**
 * Report Schema
 */
var ReportSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    required: 'Title cannot be blank'
  },
  sections: [SectionSchema],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Report', ReportSchema);
```

controller

```
/**
 * Create a report
 */
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var report = new Report(req.body);
  report.user = req.user;
   report.sections = [];
   // going over each name of sections and creating an empty object for each of them
   req.body.sections.forEach(function (section) {
     report.sections.push({
       name: section
     });
   });
  console.log(report);

  report.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(report);
    }
  });
};
```

error:

```
/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:779
      catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                                 ^

TypeError: self[i].emit is not a function
    at EventEmitter.notify (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/documentarray.js:214:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at model.Document.(anonymous function) [as emit] (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:88:42)
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:229:11
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:139:7
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:479:5
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:633:5
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:469:9
    at resultHandler (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:416:5)
    at /home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:778:13
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:249:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/binny/Programming/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Comment: Seems like the problem with the mongoose module..
Trying updating to the latest version or try to use promises instead of the callback

Comment: what if you change ``res.json(report);`` to ``res.json({});`` or ``res.json(report.toObject())``?